# can you create two types of same insert triggers on same table with different names

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

can you create two types of same insert triggers on same table with different names. suppose you have two after triggers names t1, t2 and before insert perform this action and after insert update the table

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Please note, the order of execution is not defined, so you don't know which trigger is fired first, t1 or t2. However since Oracle 11.1 you can define explicitly the order of execution by keyword [FOLLOWS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#BABGFHID)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have more triggers of the same type on one table.